# Overcurrent protection relay: how do I simulate it with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: adc, raspberry-pi, simulation, protection, level-shifting

I'm using an RPi and an MCP3208 to simulate an overcurrent relay. I managed to level-shift the AC signal and now I get the voltage reading at 0-3.3 V.

As this is an overCURRENT relay, I was stuck for a month reading books and online resources. All of them keep talking about pickup current and delay time which relates to when the relay will break the circuit. I understand some parts but not others.

My understanding:
If the pickup current is higher than the acceptable current rating, it should break the circuit.

My question:
Now what? How do I get the values needed from the table below (specifically TMS)? Do I need the current sensor for this?

[image: From my book]

ps: If my question is too much, is there any easy explanation or can anyone link to any easy books/websites for this?

---

My current data:

[image: Voltage Reading and Frequency]

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get the values needed from the table below (specifically
>   TMS)?

TMS is short for Time Multiplier Setting. On an electromechanical overcurrent relay this may be set using a calibrated dial with numbers on it, called the Time Dial Setting (TDS). A TMS value of 1 represents the relay's normal operating time. Higher or lower values increase or decrease the operating time proportionally.

> Do I need current sensor for this?

If you just want to [simulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_simulation) an overcurrent relay then you don't need any extra hardware since the Pi can do it all in software. But if you want to *emulate* it (ie. replace a physical relay with your Pi) then you will need to measure current.

> is there any easy explanation or can anyone link me to any easy
>   books/websites for this?

Here's a good article describing how these relays work and explanation of the timing equations:-

[Overcurrent Protective Relays](https://www.philadelphia.edu.jo/academics/mlazim/uploads/Power%20System%20protection%20-%20Part%2005.pdf)